# HTML Email loosing Formatting when too long on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I have an issue where it appears that *very long* HTML emails on the iPhone are not displayed properly and loose all formatting.

-

### Details:

I have a server that sends out a nightly status email to a group of users. This email is formatted in HTML and has displayed correctly on various mobile and desktop devices including the iPhone, Gmail, and Outlook. This email gets slightly longer every day as more records are reported on the email.

Last night the email stopped rendering properly on the iPhone 5 with iOS7 and the iPhone 6 with iOS8. Recipients of the email on other devices were able to view the email with the formatting, but after sending the email to iPhone recipients, the formatting was entirely removed.

My email contains only basic html tags and uses the style attribute for styling. It begins with:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></head>
<body style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;">
...
```

My college forwarded me the email, and all the HTML tags had been removed, and there were "br" tags and "nbsp" characters inserted to psudo-mock the table layout that I had.

The email length is 533,957 characters.

Are any of you familiar with this and/or know a way around it?