# SSRS Subscription - internal Exchange emails not delivering correctly to iPhone

Tags: iphone, reporting-services, exchange-server

We have an SSRS email subscription setup to deliver an administrative report once a day via our Exchange server, and it was reported that the formatting is broken.  I've done some digging, and I'm at a loss to explain what's going on.

Symptoms:
-Emails are being delivered to all recipients.
-The report is displaying correctly when loaded on a Windows PC via Outlook (both local and externally)
-The report is displaying correctly when loaded on an Android devices (both local and externaly)
-The report is displaying correctly when loaded on an iPhone synched via a GMail account, and through a University account.
-The report is displaying INCORRECTLY when loaded on an iPhone synched with Exchange.  Looking at the HTML, it appears nothing but `<span>` and `<br>` tags are being included - there's no CSS information, and none of the normal formatting tags or information I would expect to see.

Steps I have tried to get this to work:
-Enabled HTML 4.0 on the SSRS report and enabling Embedding of HTML 4.0

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?  I have not been able to locate anything helpful on Stack Overflow, or with more generic Google searches.  This thread indicates a similar problem, but has no replies - [HTML Email loosing Formatting when too long on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019373/html-email-loosing-formatting-when-too-long-on-iphone)

Comment: After researching this with our systems administrator, we confirmed this is NOT an issue with our Exchange configuration - the maximum HTML body size is set to Unlimited, and the Allow HTML Email property is set to True.  It appears that the Mail application places a cap on maximum HTML size pulled through ActiveSync.  This explains why other reports are coming through as HTML text appropriately, but the report in question is not.

Comment: What is your SSRS version? Are the reports being emailed in MHTML (web archive), PDF or some other format? Can you explain in more detail what you mean by the report displaying "incorrectly"?

Comment: After some additional investigation yesterday, it looks like the issue is stemming from an internal cap on ActiveSync on the iPhone.  Our sysadmin indicated that client-side apps maintain own internal threshhold outside the server settings, and when you cross that magic number the HTML is stripped into plain text the same way it would be if the server throttled it.  I removed a couple of grids from the report, and it dropped the report size below whatever the internal threshhold on the iPhone mail app is.  Reports are now being properly received on the users' iPhones.